# sql server: Send email about updates during transaction

Tags: sql-server

I have a job that runs clean up queries from a table. There's a cursor that rolls through the queries, if one fails there's a try catch that will get the error message from the query on the table and database. Which puts that information in an email with sp_send_dbemail.

I am wondering if it is possible to change the catch block after the query runs to look for transactions that were successful. Then get the updated rows, or maybe just IDs for the rows, and put those IDs in an email?

Or would it be easier to just look for rows to update in the query when the job is running it to create an email after the updates happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the [output clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql) might be useful here. You can find many examples of usage by searching. In short, you add the output clause to each "cleaning" statement and capture the information you need. Yes - each statement. I am doubtful about your goal - but that is a different issue.

And btw - the catch block runs when an error occurs. It does not make much sense to use the catch block to look for the effects of successful statements. In the catch block you know that the most recently executed statement in your try block **failed**. And of course, if every statement is successful the catch block never executes.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I was pretty sure the catch block idea was a no go, but figured it good to ask incase there was a edge case store proc in SSMS that I didn't know of.